# Use a contact us form to send message to Salesforce.com

Tags: contact, sales-cloud, web2lead, website-integration

I've just logged onto Salesforce.com for the first time, intrigued by the web-to-lead feature mentioned on their pricing page. Is there a way to have a contact us form generate a new customer account with their email and a create a new case or message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Web to Lead and Web to Case don't automatically create Accounts or Contacts from the information provided by the customer. Typically you'd use the Web to Lead form to capture a potential customer. This would go into Salesforce as a Lead. Once you have qualified the lead, then you would use the Convert Lead functionality in Salesforce to create an Account and Contact.

Web to Case can be used as a contact us form if you just want to record that someone contacted you and you responded.

You can also look into creating a Visualforce page hosted in a Salesforce site that can be used to create other records, do lookups to existing data a more.

Answer (score 0):

Yes If you are using a salesforce  org and want someone fill the form for contact you than you can just capture the info as a lead or a case.

Basically when the end user fill the contact form than you can eaislly generate a lead or a case  in your salesforce org and on case/lead you can write a trigger to create a account record.

This is a video link how to create a web to lead form for you site from salesforce.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c2VNmg4F4ho&noredirect=1